# has anyone here using restrict content pro?

Tags: php, plugins

I have a client who is using Restrict content pro.  Although the client likes the restrict content pro, there is one problem to it - he wants the post to be automatically changed to paid user after 10 days and RCP (Restrict Content Pro) does not provide this functionality.

Even the use of trial post will only allow the subscribe user or login user, so I have to modify base on the clients needs.

So, on the Subscription Level on the post there is default option, "all", which if you select it means the post will be available to public, but if you select the Subscription Level to another subscription say premium subscription the post will only be visible for the login user.

I want this option to automatically change when the publish date reach 10 days, so if the post is not yet 10 days old it will be free.  But, if the post reaches 10 days it will be premium.  Hopefully, you can help me this matter

Here is the original code:

```
case 'levels':
echo '<select name="', $field['id'] . '" id="' . $field['id'] . '">';

$levels = rcp_get_subscription_levels( 'all', false );
echo '<option value="all">' . __( 'All', 'rcp' ) . '</option>';
foreach ($levels as $level) {
    echo '<option value="' . $level->id . '"', $meta == $level->id ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>',     $level->name, '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
break;
```

Here is my modified code which is not working:

```
//modification end here
$pubdate = the_date();
if (($pubdate < 10) == true){
    $levels = rcp_get_subscription_levels( 'all', false );
    echo '<option value="all">' . __( 'All', 'rcp' ) . '</option>';
} else{
    foreach ($levels as $level) {
        echo '<option value="' . $level->id . '"', $meta == $level->id ? ' selected="selected"' : '',     '>',     $level->name, '</option>';
    }
}
//modification end here
```

Comment: Can you add some punctuation and capitals to your text? I have a hard time reading it.

Comment: @John Added edit that does that.  Could you approve it?

Comment: Looks much better, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here with your solution is that you are trying to update the administrator interface (used to choose if you want your content to be paid or accessible by members only). In other words, you are trying to hack the code in the wrong place.

Instead, I'd take a look to the custom fields that are being saved when you choose the properties of Restrict Content Pro. I just run a test in one of my websites which is also powered by Restrict Content Pro and after creating a dummy post and configuring it for Paid users only and a specific user plan, I noticed that there are a few custom field values saved (you can see this in the database using phpMyAdmin or any other DB interface, the reason why I suggest this instead of the Custom Fields metabox in WordPress is because there are some fields that are serialized and not displayed in the meta box).

In my test I noticed the following values where changed for a dummy post.

```
Custom Field Name       Example of Value
----------------------------------------
rcp_access_level        None
rcp_subscription_level  a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2";}
rcp_user_level          All
```

So, in order to implement what you need I'd try to run a script in the WordPress cron job that searches for the posts within the 10 days and then updates these custom field values for the post accordingly.

In order to see what to change, I'd recommend to take a look at the code that is on
restrict-content-pro\includes\admin\metabox.php line 140 (** this may be different in your version) to see what is inside the function rcp_save_meta_data( $post_id ).

Particularly you may need to update `rcp_subscription_level` value to use the plan level that you want the content to be protected with. Instead, if you want your content to be protected by user levels then update the `rcp_user_level`.